# exception while using scribe for twitter auth

Tags: java, scribe

I receive the following exception while trying to retrieve access token using the service.getAccessToken call (it takes the request Token and verifier as parameters).

```
accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

**Exception:
Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from an empty string**
The exception comes from the token extractor in scribe.  The request token appears to be valid and the verifier is not null either.  Any suggestions to further troubleshoot/fix the issue would be welcome.  I am using JDK 1.6.  Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can you please turn scribe's debug mode on (`debug()` method on `ServiceBuilder`) and copy the output?

Comment: thanks for responding - I will do that.  I was able to fix the issue by switching back to my code which was previously working - I will update this post later today.  once again, thanks for responding

Comment: late update (& I don't have all the facts) - I was able to get scribe working properly and the above mentioned issue was due to misuse of the library (not an issue with the library itself).